# How to return a constant view of a std::string?

Tags: c++, string, string-view

While prototyping and playing around in C++, trying some concepts for making a utf8-aware immutable string, I stood with the following dilemma:

Is there any way to return a immutable view of a string. Like, instead of returning a substring, I want to be able to return a substring that references a part of the original string.

```
// Just some quick prototyping of ideas.
// Heavier than just a normal string.
// Construction would be heavier too because of the indices vector.
// Size would end up being O1 though.
// Indexing would also be faster.

struct ustring {
    std::string data;
    std::vector<size_t> indices;

    // How do I return a view to a string?

    std::string operator [](size_t const i) const {
        return data.substr(indices[i], indices[i + 1] - indices[i]);
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you have the `string_view` class available to you from c++17?

Comment: alternately, some libraries implemented `<experimental/string_view>` in c++14, and before that, boost had a string_view library. You could also use the GSL.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) is the class for you! If you don't have C++17 support, then try out [`std::experimental::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view). If that's not available, try out [`boost::string_view`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/boost/utility/string_view.hpp). All of those choices can be used in the same way (just replace `std::string_view` with whatever you use):

```
std::string_view operator [](size_t const i) const {
    return std::string_view(&data[i], 1);
}
```

Welcome to C++, where there's always another kitchen sink!

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 the header does appear in the intellisense, however, when I do `std::` there's no `string_view` nor `experimental::string_view` available. Maybe they just reserved the word for future use?

Comment: Did you `#include <string_view>` or `#include <experimental/string_view>`?

Comment: #include <string_view>

Comment: Does compilation fail at the `#include` or at the attempt to use `std::string_view`? (I'm grasping a bit here -- I don't really use Visual Studio or MSVC)

Comment: There's actualy no member in `std` called `string_view`. I also prefer to program C++ in sublime with g++, but I'm stuck at gcc 5.2.0. Also, just out of curiosity, would `std::string_view` be accepted in functions with `std::string` as parameter or does it need to be overloaded?

Comment: Can you open the header for `<string_view>` (usually Ctrl+click)? You should find a class called `basic_string_view` and a type definition named `string_view` inside of it. (As a side note, a "member" in C++ is something nested inside of a type -- in your example, `data` is a member of the `ustring` type)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133305/discussion-between-travis-gockel-and-dagoberto-pires).